# Why isnt the output showing k1, k2, k3?

Tags: python

I've been trying to learn Python and have come across this issue. I can't figure out how the current output came about.

```
d={'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3}
for key,value in d.keys() :
    print(key)

Output:

k
k
k
```

I expected the output to be:

```
k1
k2
k3
```

Comment: Then why are using taking `key,value`. Use `key` for only keys.

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57232805/3091398) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to print all key, value pair from your dictionary `d`. But you are only able to see first character of the key when you try to print `key`. I will explain you by splitting your for loop `for key,value in d.keys()`.

This is your dictionary, `d`

```
d = {'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3}
```

The `for` loop takes `d.keys()` and iterates. `d.keys()` look like this

```
print(d.keys()) # outputs dict_keys(['k1', 'k2', 'k3'])
```

`for` loop iterates over this list of keys `['k1', 'k2', 'k3']`

But when you do, this

```
key,value = 'k1' # this happens with each of the keys in the list 
print(key,value) # output k 1
```

Your key `k1` got split into two single character strings `k` and `1` which can be termed as an *unintentional tuple creation* [@inquisitiveOne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233040/3091398) and gets assigned to `key` and `value` variables respectively.

When you try to print `value` inside the `for` loop, you will see `1, 2, 3` but that is in fact the second character of the `key` attribute and not the `value` attribute. If you try printing, `print(type(value))` you will get to know that it is in fact a `string` variable and not an `integer`.

---

To get the proper value of the `key` you need to only use a single variable.

```
d={'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3}
for key in d.keys():
    print(key)
```

Output:

```
k1
k2
k3
```

As mentioned by [@asikorski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232777/why-isnt-the-output-showing-k1-k2-k3/57232823#comment100969921_57232805) you can achieve the same using just `for key in d: print(key)`

---

If you need to get key, value pairs. Then use `d.items()`

```
for key,value in d.items():
    print(key,value)
```

Output:

```
k1 1
k2 2
k3 3
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

`d.keys()` returns `['k1', 'k2', 'k3']`, but you split that into two parts with `key, value`, so `key=='k'`, `value=='1'` the first time, and `key=='k'`, `value=='2'` the second time, and so on. What you want is:

```
for key in d.keys():
    print(key)
```

But you can do better and iterate directly over the dictionary without using the `.keys()` method:

```
for key in d:
    print(key)
```

Finally, if you need to use both keys and values:

```
for key, values in d.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

`d.keys()` is a list and it's value will be `["k1", "k2", "k3"]`

```
>> d.keys()
["k1", "k2", "k3"]
```

When you use `for key,value in d.keys()`, unpacking will happen on the string value. Which means from `"k1"`, "k" will be assigned to key and "1" will be assigned to value.

Luckily it didn't give error because there were only 2 characters in the string.

```
>> key, value = "k1"
>> key
k
>> value
1
```

And, that is the reason it printed `k k k` in console.!

The right way is to iterate through `k.items()`

```
for key,value in d.items():
    print(key,value)
```

Output

```
k1 1
k2 2
k3 3
```

Comment: *`d.keys()` is a list* is not true, it's not a list, it's a `dict_keys` object. I would rather simply say it's an *iterable*.

Comment: My fault @asikorski, I am still using Python2.7 & in that, `d.keys()` is of type `list`. I have verified that it will be of type `list` in python2 & `dict_keys` in Python3. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3}
for key in d.keys() :
    print(key)
```

Try this code, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

for getting the keys you need the keys API:

```
  d={'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3}
    for key in d.keys() :
        print(key)
```

for getting the values use the values API:

```
 d={'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3}
    for value in d.values() :
        print(value)
```

for getting keys and values there is the items API:

```
 d={'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3}
    for key,value in d.items() :
        print(key)
        print(value)
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Answer is **unintentional tuple creation**.

In the statement:

```py
for key,value in d.keys() :
```

you are creating a **tuple** unintentionally.

```py
>>> key, value = "k1"
>>> key
'k'
>>> value
'1'
```

Note that the **brackets are optional for creating a tuple**. 
The above is the same as:

```py
>>> (key, value) = "k1"
>>> key
'k'
>>> value
'1'
>>>
```

Hence the output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `for loop`:

```
for key,value in d.keys() :
```

`d.keys()` is an iterable (technically a `dict_keys` object) that contains only the keys of `d`: `k1`, `k2`, and `k3`.

Your `for loop` unpacks each string into `k` (represented by `key`) and a number (represented by `value`). You then print only `key`, which in each instance is `k`.

---

To remedy the issue, simply stop unpacking the keys:

```
for key in d.keys():
```